# Query Postgres Json Field using EF Core 5

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, c#-9.0

I have the following table definition

```
  [Table("MyTable")]
  public class MyTable: BaseEntity
  {
    [Required]
    public string A{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "json")]
    public string B{ get; set; }
  }
```

Column B looks like this:

```
{"Data": [{"Id":"b8a3cbbc-a4d6-4697-8a0b-cb1d15be179d"}]} (aside from Id there are other properties but for brevity I removed them)
```

In Entity Framework I want to match all MyTable's where the Id in B is a certain value and A has a certain value.  I have tried a lot of things and get numerous errors.  How can I add to the following code to achieve what I want?

```
var results = 
   _repository.Get<MyTable>(_ => _.A == "Something" && _.B = ???);
```

Comment: If you need to query the data often, create a separate, indexed table. Even with JSON indexes, access will always be slower than trying to access a normal table, no matter the RDBMS. Since the field actually contains *object* data, it should be treated either as an entity or a value object. That means it needs its own type and to be parsed *before* mapping. You can map entities to views, or use `FromSqlRaw/Interpolated` to "unpack" the JSON data

Comment: What you ask is how to map data in a certain format to application objects. That's obviously the job of the mapping model, not the ORM queries that use it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how do I query the data without bringing back all the records in the table and then mapping to objects before querying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "`EF.Functions.JsonContains`" function, but the `B` column needs to be "`jsonb`" type instead of "`json`".

```
    [Required]
    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public string B { get; set; }
```

Example:

```cs
var search = "[{\"Id\": \"b8a3cbbc-a4d6-4697-8a0b-cb1d15be179d\"}]";
var results = _context.MyTable2
      .Where(_ => _.A == "Something" 
                    && EF.Functions.JsonContains(_.B, search));
```

Similar answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297975/how-to-query-against-a-column-that-has-a-json-array-in-npgsql-entityframeworkcor)

Also, you can type your query and use Dapper.

Example:

```
 with temp AS(
  select t."Id", t."A", json_array_elements(t."B"->'Data') as B1 from "MyTable"  t
  )
  select * from temp t
  where 
  t."A"='Something' and
  t.b1->>'Id'='b9a3cbbc-a4d6-4697-8a0b-cb1d15be179a'
```