# How to perform a simple query on a join table when the join table is created by EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

Say I have two entities with a many-to-many relationship and create the join table manually:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserPermission> UserPermissions { get; set; }
}

public class UserPermission
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

If I want to find out if a user has a specific permission I can run a simple query like this

```
var query = _context.UserPermissions
    .Where(up => up.UserId == userId && up.PermissionId == permissionId);
```

Now say I remove the join table and let entity framework create it for me:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

How can I perform this same simple query on the db without pulling in a load of unnecessary data or overcomplicating the query?

Answer (score 0):

The EF will create UserPermissions for you. Please find at the following [LINK](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I know but that's not the question.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use the "UserPermissions" table. The other solution is to add a json field (Permissions) at the User table and use "EF.Functions" for query Example here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439395/query-postgres-json-field-using-ef-core-5/68484046#68484046