# Query nested jsonb with LINQ

Tags: c#, postgresql, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an entity `Advisor` with a column of type `jsonb`.

```
[Column(TypeName = "jsonb")] 
public ExpertiseArea ExpertiseArea { get; set; } = new();
```

```
public class ExpertiseArea
{
    public List<TripCountry> TripCountries { get; set; } = new List<TripCountry>();
}
```

```
public class TripCountry
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Assume the following LINQ query:

```cs
var query = query.Where(a 
    => a.ExpertiseArea.TripCountries.Any(tc 
        => queryParams.Directions.Contains(tc.Id)))
```

`queryParams.Directions` is an `int[]`.

I want to select `Advisor` entities where `ExpertiseArea.TripCountries` contain each of `queryParams.Directions` int values.

Here is the JSON example:

```json
{   
    "TripCountries": [
        { "Id": 3, "Name": "Austria" }, 
        { "Id": 83, "Name": "France" }, 
        { "Id": 6, "Name": "Poland" }
    ]
}
```

For example, `queryParams.Directions` is `[3,6]`.

I want all the advisors with `TripCountries` having both Poland and Austria.

I tried to write it with `EF.Functions` but I'm not sure which exact function to use.

I tried to resolve it with ChatGPT, but it gives wrong answers only.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can pull the useful information from my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68439395/query-postgres-json-field-using-ef-core-5/68484046#68484046

Comment: Thanks for reply. Well, JsonContains is not solution for me, because I need check for a list of values, not a single value

Comment: Added an answer, based on JsonContains. It works, but I still believe there is more elegant solution. Thank you

Comment: I'm glad that you find a working solution ;)

Answer (score 2):

Didn't found an elegant solution but using `EF.Functions.JsonContains` we can compare to a single value. And with `foreach` we can add multiple comparations.

This is what worked for me:

```
        string contained;
        foreach (var direction in queryParams.Directions)
        {
            contained = $"[{{\"Id\": {direction}}}]";
            query = query.Where(a => EF.Functions.JsonContains(a.ExpertiseArea.TripCountries, contained));
        }
```